# pyserial: Force Arduino to /dev/ACM0?

Tags: python, usb, raspbian-jessie, serial, arduino

(Using Raspberry Pi 3B, Raspbian Jessie)

I have a Python script that uses an Arduino with Pyserial.

I want to start this script on boot, but my problem is that sometimes the Arduino binds to /dev/ttyACM0, and sometimes to /dev/ttyACM1.

If it binds to the one that's not specified in the script, the script fails.

Is there a way to force one or the other? And if not, is there a way I can switch from one to the other in the script?

Comment: this is more a question of port enumeration than about python, and it has been asked and answered before

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is get your script to run the OS command `ls /dev | ttyACM` and redirect the output to a variable you will use in your script. That way, your script won't care where the Arduino connects.

Comment: I think you wanted `ls /dev/ttyACM*` or `ls /dev | grep ttyACM`. Also, you might want to show how to save the output in a variable.